# Operations not working using REST, but working otherwise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, express

It's kind of weird, but I have no idea what might be the cause for this madness.

I have this code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var AdModule = require('../models/ad');

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next(); // User is logged in
    }
    res.redirect('/users/login');
}

router.route('/')
    .get((req, res) => {
        AdModule.find((err, col) => {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            res.render('ads/', {
                user: req.user,
                ads: col,
                title: "Ads"
            });
        })
    });

router.route('/create')
    .get(isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
        res.render('ads/create', {
            user: req.user,
            title: "Ads"
        });
    })
    .post(isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
        var ad = new AdModule();
        ad.title = req.body.title;
        ad.desc = req.body.desc;
        ad.price = req.body.price;
        ad.save(err => {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/ads');
        });
    });

router.route('/:_id')
    .get(isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
        console.log('tada');
        AdModule.findById(req.params._id, (err, obj) => {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            res.render('ads/edit', {
                ad: obj,
                title: 'Edit ad',
                user: req.user
            });
        })
    })
    .post(isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
        AdModule.findById(req.params._id, (err, obj) => {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            obj.title = req.body.title;
            obj.desc = req.body.desc;
            obj.price = req.body.price;
            obj.save(err => {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err);
                res.redirect('/ads');
            });
        })
    });

router.route('/remove/:_id')
    .post(isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
        AdModule.remove({_id: req.params._id}, (err, obj) => {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/ads');
        })
    });

module.exports = router;
```

This code is not RESTful, but works. The database is being updated, and it's all good.

Now this is my attempt to get it working as API. The code is the same, the only difference are the routes, and the returns. The operations are copy-pasted.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var AdModule = require('../../models/ad');

router.route('/')
    .get((req, res) => {
        AdModule.find((err, col) => {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(col);
        })
    })
    .post((req, res) => {
        var ad = new AdModule();
        ad.title = req.body.title;
        ad.desc = req.body.desc;
        ad.price = req.body.price;
        ad.save(err => {
            if (err)
                res.send('err' + err);
            res.json({msg: 'Created'});
        });
    });

router.route('/:_id')
    .get((req, res) => {
        AdModule.findById(req.params._id, (err, obj) => {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(obj);
        })
    })
    .put((req, res) => {
        AdModule.findById(req.params._id, (err, obj) => {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            console.log(obj);
            console.log(req.params._id);
            obj.title = req.body.title;
            obj.desc = req.body.desc;
            obj.price = req.body.price;
            obj.save(err => {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);
                res.json({msg: 'Updated'});
            });
        })
    })
    .delete((req, res) => {
        AdModule.remove({_id: req.params._id}, (err, obj) => {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json({msg: 'Removed'});
        })
    });

module.exports = router;
var a = {
    "desc": "Hi. I'd like to sell shoes",
    "price": 12.28,
    "title": "Selling shoes"
};
```

As you see the code is pretty much the same. But when I use postman to update, or create new objects, it creates them, but without the `title`, `description` and `price` fields. So I'm guessing there is something wrong with the model (found here)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var AdSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    desc: String,
    price: Number,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Ad', AdSchema);
```

But I don't know what. The path appears to be correct, there are no errors, and postman returns `message: "created"` and `message: "updated"`.

```
{
    "msg": "Created"
}
```

And this is what the GET looks like now.

```
{
    "_id": "5ac2bfd4bd478155ac1eba37",
    "title": "b",
    "desc": "b",
    "price": 2,
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "5ac2c1726995a75700cef8eb",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Any idea where my problem is?

My create form:

```
<% include ../partials/header.ejs %>
<form method="post" action="/ads/create">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Enter title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="desc">Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="desc" id="desc" placeholder="Enter description">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Enter price">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
<% include ../partials/footer.ejs %>
```

This is what I'm passing into Postman

```
"title":"test",
"desc":"test",
"price":12312,
```

Comment: Can I see what your form looked like originally?

Comment: Could you also provide your postman "create" and "update" logs?

Comment: @JSilv updated the post.

@Alex If by logs you mean the responses they're up there.
`{
    "msg": "Created"
}`
 If not plz explain how to get different logs

Comment: Can you log what `req.body` is?

Comment: How do I do this in Postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Turns out I need to send it like this using postman:

```
desc:Hi. I'd like to sell shoes again
price:12.28
title:Selling shoes
```